# обновление cookie php

Tags: php, html, cookie

Привет всем! Есть вот такой маленький скриптец для записи `cookie` через `select`.

Скрипт:

```
    if (isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['month'])){
        setcookie("year", "");
setcookie("month", "");
setcookie("year", $_POST['year']);
setcookie("month", $_POST['month']);

         echo '<h1>'.$_COOKIE['year'].'<br>';
         echo $_COOKIE['month'].'</h1>';
```

Форма:

```
<form id="filter" method="post"> 
<select name="month" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
<option value="">Выберите месяц...</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==1) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="1">Январь</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==2) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="2">Февраль</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==3) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="3">Март</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==4) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="4">Апрель</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==5) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="5">Май</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==6) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="6">Июнь</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==7) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="7">Июль</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==8) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="8">Август</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==9) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="9">Сентябрь</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==10) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="10">Октябрь</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==11) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="11">Ноябрь</option>
    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['month']==12) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="12">Декабрь</option>
</select>
<select name="year" style="margin-bottom:0px;">    
<option value="">Выберите год...</option>
    <option value="2015" <?php if($_COOKIE['year']==2015) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>2015</option>
    <option value="2016" <?php if($_COOKIE['year']==2016) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>2016</option>
    <option value="2017" <?php if($_COOKIE['year']==2017) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>2017</option>
    <option value="2018" <?php if($_COOKIE['year']==2018) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>2018</option>
    <option value="2019" <?php if($_COOKIE['year']==2019) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>2019</option>
    <option value="2020" <?php if($_COOKIE['year']==2020) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>2020</option>
    <option value="2021" <?php if($_COOKIE['year']==2021) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>2021</option>
</select>

<?php    
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Вывести" name="vivod"></input>
</form>
```

Дело в том, что куки записывается, но вот вывод новой куки например через `echo` происходит только после повторного обновления...

Comment: Ну да, оно так и работает. Когда вы ставите куку она отправляется клиенту. И при следующем его запросе он вам ее присылает и вы ее видите в $_COOKIE. Введите свою переменную, в которую будете класть $_POST, если он есть, а если его нет - то куку. И по этой переменной делайте свои if

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Все сделал))

Comment: @Mike, дабы выйти из беты, нам надо как можно больше отвеченных вопросов. Добавь свой ответ из коммента.

Answer (score 1):

Да, куки так и работают. Когда вы ставите куку она отправляется клиенту. И только при следующем его запросе он вам ее присылает и вы ее видите в `$_COOKIE`. Введите свою переменную, в которую будете класть `$_POST`, если он есть, а если его нет - то куку. И по этой переменной делайте свои `if`

Answer (score 0):

Почему так происходит вам ответил @Mike. А что вам мешает сделать так?

```
if (isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['month'])){
    setcookie("year", $_POST['year']);
    setcookie("month", $_POST['month']);
    echo '<h1>' . $_POST['year'] . '<br>' . $_POST['month'] . '</h1>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто делай перезапись куки и все.